# Using parameterised LIKE clauses in an EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sql-like, entitydatasource

I have a basic `EntityDataSource` bound to a `GridView`. I have `TextBox` above the `GridView` for searching.

My goal:
a) User types "jon"
b) GridView` is filtered, e.g. "Jonathan","Enjona","Jonas".

I have seen several examples of how to add a parameterised LIKE clause to the Where property of my data source, however they all need the user to use a wildcard in the search string (e.g. %Jon instead of Jon). This is not really acceptable for lay users, so I want to put the wildcard in the Where clause instead.

The syntax in SQL is obvious: `SELECT Name FROM Names WHERE Name LIKE N'%@p1%'`

In other words, if `@p1='Jon'`, my WHERE clause is LIKE `N'%Jon%'`.

Frustratingly, the Where clause in the `EntityDataSource` doesn't seem to work this way. In other words, the following does not work:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsNames" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=SalesEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="SalesEntities" EntitySetName="Names"
    OrderBy="it.Name" Where="it.Name LIKE '%@p1%'">
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtFilter" Name="p1" 
            PropertyName="Text" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
    </WhereParameters>
</asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I would happily expect the default value of "" to provide me with my "get everything" clause, i.e. `LIKE '%%'`, but nothing is returned in my `GridView`.

Frustratingly, if I hard-code a search result, e.g. `Where="it.Name LIKE '%Jon%'"`, it works perfectly.

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I got it working like this:

```
Where="it.Name like ('%' + @p1 + '%')"
```

This works with .NET 3.5 - I think QueryExtender plus OnQueryCreated (this would also have been an option for adapting the query before it gets run) are only available in .NET >= 4.0.

Answer (score 3):

you  could try writing the where condition as follows

```
Where="@p1 IS NULL OR it.Name LIKE '%@p1%'"
```

just in case it is seen as a null value

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using a QueryExtender. Something along these lines:

```
  <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsEmployeeSearch" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="name=HrProtoEntities" DefaultContainerName="HrProtoEntities" 
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="People" Include="Employee" 
    AutoGenerateWhereClause="True" >
</asp:EntityDataSource>
<asp:QueryExtender ID="QueryExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="edsEmployeeSearch">
    <asp:SearchExpression SearchType="Contains" DataFields="LastName">
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" />
    </asp:SearchExpression>
</asp:QueryExtender>
```